# Playing mp3 on Android?

Tags: android, python, kivy, audio-player

I am trying to make an audio player for Kivy as a personal project however I noticed that my app fails to load mp3 audio. After a little research it seems to be related to some licensing issue? In any case androids can still play mp3 files of course so what can I do to make this happen?

As it stands I am using the normal SoundLoader() class from kivy. I think my android audio is using sdl2 but I could be mistaken as I am not sure where to check this I just remember seeing it somewhere. I have also tried changing the KIVY_AUDIO environment variable but it didn't work (I assume I did something wrong).

Does anyone know of any work arounds because I can't seem to find any?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the kivy SoundLoader class has some problems (eg. it does not seek correctly in certain mp3 files). As Joey mentions the original android class which can be accessed by jnius works better and with most songfiles you throw at it (mp3, mp4, flac,waves etc.)

I made two working classes, one for android which uses jnius and one for windows (of course the android class does not work here).

You may have to update to the newest kivy and add gstreamer like described in the documentation. 
and: kivy logger has some problems with unicode on android and throws an exception when printing. sound plays fine though. If the exception annoys you, delete the kivy.info lines.

```
#coding: utf-8

from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader
from kivy.utils import platform 
from kivy.logger import Logger
import time

class MusicPlayerAndroid(object):
    def __init__(self):

        from jnius import autoclass
        MediaPlayer = autoclass('android.media.MediaPlayer')
        self.mplayer = MediaPlayer()

        self.secs = 0
        self.actualsong = ''
        self.length = 0
        self.isplaying = False

    def __del__(self):
        self.stop()
        self.mplayer.release()
        Logger.info('mplayer: deleted')

    def load(self, filename):
        try:
            self.actualsong = filename
            self.secs = 0
            self.mplayer.setDataSource(filename)        
            self.mplayer.prepare()
            self.length = self.mplayer.getDuration() / 1000
            Logger.info('mplayer load: %s' %filename)
            Logger.info ('type: %s' %type(filename) )
            return True
        except:
            Logger.info('error in title: %s' % filename) 
            return False

    def unload(self):
            self.mplayer.reset()

    def play(self):
        self.mplayer.start()
        self.isplaying = True
        Logger.info('mplayer: play')

    def stop(self):
        self.mplayer.stop()
        self.secs=0
        self.isplaying = False
        Logger.info('mplayer: stop')

    def seek(self,timepos_secs):
        self.mplayer.seekTo(timepos_secs * 1000)
        Logger.info ('mplayer: seek %s' %int(timepos_secs))


class MusicPlayerWindows(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.secs = 0
        self.actualsong = ''
        self.length = 0
        self.isplaying = False
        self.sound = None

    def __del__(self):
        if self.sound:
            self.sound.unload()
            Logger.info('mplayer: deleted')

    def load(self, filename):
        self.__init__()
        if type(filename) == unicode: filename = filename.encode('utf-8') #unicode does not work ! 
        self.sound = SoundLoader.load(filename)    
        if self.sound:
            if self.sound.length != -1 :
                self.length = self.sound.length
                self.actualsong = filename
                Logger.info('mplayer: load %s' %filename)
                return True
            else:
                Logger.info ('mplayer: songlength = -1 ...')
        return False

    def unload(self):
        if self.sound != None:
            self.sound.unload()
            self.__init__ # reset vars

    def play(self):
        if self.sound:
            self.sound.play()
            self.isplaying = True
            Logger.info('mplayer: play')

    def stop(self):
        self.isplaying = False
        self.secs=0
        if self.sound:
            self.sound.stop()
            Logger.info('mplayer: stop')

    def seek(self, timepos_secs):
        self.sound.seek(timepos_secs)
        Logger.info('mplayer: seek %s' %int(timepos_secs))

def main():
    songs = [
        'f:\\_mp3_\\_testdir_\\file of ☠☢☣.mp3', #insert songs here
        'f:\\_mp3_\\Patricks Mp3s\\electro\\Echotek - Freak Africa.mp3',
        'f:\\_mp3_diverse_\\Testsuite\\flac\\01 - Jam & Spoon - Stella (Jam & Spoon Mix).flac',
        'f:\\_mp3_\\P1\\1Start\\Hot Chip - boy from school.mp4'
        ]

    Logger.info ('platform: %s' %platform)

    if platform == 'win':
        mplayer = MusicPlayerWindows()
    elif platform == 'android':
        mplayer = MusicPlayerAndroid()
    else:
        exit()

    for s in songs:
        if mplayer.load(s): # checking load, seek
            mplayer.play()
            time.sleep(2)
            mplayer.seek(90)
            time.sleep(2)
            mplayer.stop()
            mplayer.unload()

        else:
            Logger.info ('cant load song: %s' %s)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: This is an amazing answer thank you very much. I will definitely vote this as correct answer. I just have one question though, I currently bind to on_stop to loop the music. Is there a way I can do this now? I am doing it with setLooping which sort of works but I need a way to set isplaying to be False when the sound ends naturally.

Comment: Hi John, I am currently on holidays but will look into this in 10 days to complete the class. In my kivy app I use a kivy timer with the song time which counts down when starting the song.

Comment: Hey thank you for the help I actually forgot about this comment sorry. I managed to implement an onCompletionListener. If anyone is reading this and wants to do the same this is what helped me: https://gist.github.com/ivlevdenis/02d1017ccf860276ab7d. You can use self.mplayers.setOnCompletionListener(self._complete_callback)

Answer (score 1):

check this out [playing an audio file](https://github.com/kivy/pyjnius/blob/master/docs/source/android.rst)

Comment: I am sure this would work unfortunately I didn't really plan ahead and my app is currently already using  the kivy setup and I would like to avoid having to change it all. I was hoping I could just change the provider? If it comes to it and I have to do this method though I will.